# Django 1.8 to 1.9 migrations upgrade problem

Tags: upgrade, django

Just installed Django 1.9 and am attempting to upgrade my 1.8 app.
After trying to follow the release notes carefully, I still get the following trace (see below).

I thought it had something to do with migrations, but emptying the migrations folder has no effect.

Can someone point me at a link to what I am missing?

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x9757454>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 197, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 115, in load_disk
    app_config.label,
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I had South installed which contains an old version of the Migrate class.  It was not an INSTALLED_APP settings.py.
But, I did have django-extensions installed.  This old version referenced South, which brought in the South version of Migrate, not the new django version.

The solution was to "sudo pip uninstall south" and "sudo pip install django-extensions --upgrade".

All fixed.

The trick was to use the "inspect" module to print out the file names of the classes and parent classes in loader.py where it was failing:

```
            import inspect
            print( '****', inspect.getfile(migration_module.Migration) )
            print( '********', inspect.getfile(inspect.getmro(migration_module.Migration)[1]) )
```

That quickly showed that loader.py was getting the wrong version of Migrate.